# Projet GWT: online auction website using GWT

Tags: gwt, project

for university I have to design and build an online auction website using GWT.
But the professor did not give us any material to study, do you have any guides, links or videos?

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources on the web. A good point to start is: https://dev.to/ibaca/modern-gwt-first-steps-509k

To create a running GWT project, you can use:

- https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui/wiki/Getting-started (see dominokit-cli)
- http://www.mvp4g.org/boot-starter-nalu/BootStarterNalu.html (generating a Nalu project)

I would use Nalu (Disclaimer: I am the auther of Nalu) and suggest to use Domino-UI for the visual components (https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-ui) and domino-rest (https://github.com/DominoKit/domino-rest) for the client-server communication.

in case you need help, you can ask questions here:

- GWT: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt
- Nalu: https://gitter.im/Nalukit42/Lobby
- Domino related stuff: https://gitter.im/DominoKit/domino

Hope that help.